# split() cutting off important form entry information when a new line is used in form submission

Tags: javascript, split, zapier

I'm trying to pass through information from a gravity form submission on a Woocommerce order for use in another app using Zapier. I need to split the form entry information so that the information is not all on a single line and can be individually accessed.

As I'm quite new to JavaScript, I have been struggling for hours trying to get this to work... The code I am using is from the woocommerce documentation. The problem is that a chunk of information can be cut off if said information continues onto a new line. Please see **the result of the split** below and refer to **Question 2** to see what I am talking about.

**Code:**

```
 // Define "metaData" in the Input Data section. Ignore the "No Data" label.
// Reformat Resource Meta Data to generate keyvalue pairs.
// In case of multiple equal keys, only the last value available.
const buffer = {};
const metaData = inputData.metaData.split(/\n+/);
metaData.forEach((dataString, index) => {
  if (dataString.includes('id:')) {
    const key = metaData[index + 1].replace('key:', '').trim();
    const value = metaData[index + 2].replace('value:', '').trim();
    buffer[key] = value;
  }
});
return buffer;
```

**An example form submission would like like this:**

```
Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Email: john.doe@gmail.com
Question 1: this is my first question
Question 2: hi there,
            this is my second question..

            regards, john doe
Question 3: This is my third question
```

**What the result of the split looks like:**

```
Name: John

Last Name: Doe

Email: john.doe@gmail.com

Question 1: this is my first question

Question 2: hi there,

Question 3: This is my third question
```

As you can see, Question 2 basically missing.. I have been unable to figure out a way to get this working. I hope that someone is able to lend me a hand here...

**EDIT:**
**__________________**

**RAW as requested:**

```
id: 419*** key: _gravity_forms_history value: {'_gravity_form_cart_item_key': '************************************', '_gravity_form_linked_entry_id': ****, '_gravity_form_lead': {'2': 'This is my first question', '6': 'john.doe@gmail.com', '7': '2020-08-01', '8': 'hi there,\r\nthis is my second question..\r\n\r\nregards, john doe', '9': 'This is my third question', '11': 0, '12': this is a random form entry', 'form_id': '3', 'source_url': 'https://***************************/', 'ip': ***************', '5.2': '', '5.3': 'John', '5.4': '', '5.6': 'Doe', '5.8': '', '10.1': 'Product Name', '10.2': '$0.00', '10.3': '1'}, '_gravity_form_data': {'id': '3', 'bulk_id': 0, 'display_title': False, 'display_description': False, 'disable_woocommerce_price': 'no', 'price_before': '', 'price_after': '', 'disable_calculations': 'yes', 'disable_label_subtotal': 'yes', 'disable_label_options': 'yes', 'disable_label_total': 'yes', 'disable_anchor': 'no', 'label_subtotal': 'Subtotal', 'label_options': 'Options', 'label_total': 'Total', 'use_ajax': 'no', 'enable_cart_edit': 'no', 'enable_cart_edit_remove': 'yes', 'keep_cart_entries': 'no', 'send_notifications': 'no', 'enable_cart_quantity_management': 'no', 'cart_quantity_field': '', 'update_payment_details': 'no', 'display_totals_location': 'after', 'structured_data_override': 'no', 'structured_data_low_price': '', 'structured_data_high_price': '', 'structured_data_override_type': 'append'}}
 
id: 419***
key: Name
value: John Doe

id: 419***
key: Email
value: john.doe@gmail.com

id: 419***
key: Date of Birth
value: 01.08.2020

id: 419***
key: Question 1
value: This is my first question

id: 419***
key: Question 2
value: hi there,
this is my second question..
regards, john doe

id: 419***
key: Question 3
value: This is my third question

id: 419***
key: Final Entry (Optional)
value: this is a random form entry
```

**Expected result as requested:**

```
Name: John Doe

Email: john.doe@gmail.com

Date of Birth: 01.08.2020

Question 1: This is my first question

Question 2 :Hi There,
            This Is My Second Question..

            Regards, John Doe

Question 3: This is my third question

Final Entry: this is a random form entry

id: ******************************

runtime_meta:

memory_used_mb: 72

duration_ms: 100

logs:

async: false
```

**Current result as requested:**

```
Name: John Doe

Email: john.doe@gmail.com

Date of Birth: 01.08.2020

Question 1: This is my first question

Question 2 :Hi There,

Question 3: This is my third question

Final Entry: this is a random form entry

id: ******************************

runtime_meta:

memory_used_mb: 72

duration_ms: 100

logs:

async: false
```

Comment: can you share the raw object and the expected result you want from that? would be easier to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @stranded Hey, I have provided the information you have requested at the end of my post :)

Comment: hey, thanks, from the data I can't make a link how you assign specific keys to values right now, as you mentioned you want `This is my first question` to be `Question 1` but from the data you provided it is mapped to a key `2` `'2': 'This is my first question', '6': 'john.doe@gmail.com'`
do you also store a map somewhere which links these two things?

Comment: The input forms are mapped in gravity forms as "Field ID 2" or "Field ID 6" ,  This is also where they get their label from (such as "question 1"), where the label is "Field Label". Please check "current result" and "expected result" under EDIT in my post above :)

Comment: I'm sure this can be done in a better way but right now my brain is not working, https://jsfiddle.net/8j9264va/2/
This combines the strings which do not have `id:`, `key:`, or `value:` in it with the value

Comment: I suppose you're following the [woocommerce zapier integration documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-zapier/). From that it looks like the problem is how zapier handles `metaData` but essentially this should be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What the result of the split looks like:**
>
> ```
> Name: John
> Last Name: Doe
>
> Email: john.doe@gmail.com
>
> Question 1: this is my first question
>
> Question 2: hi there,
>
> Question 3: This is my third question
> ```

No, no, no, no, no.  This is what you *think* the result of splitting is. You have a bug in your code and you have chosen to believe that the `split` function is at fault rather than your code.

In your `forEach` loop, add a line such as

```
console.log('XXXX', dataString);
```

immediately above the line `if (dataString.includes('id:')) {`.  You will see every line of your input logged out with the `XXXX` prefix, including those you claim to be missing.

So why *is* your code not doing what you want?  Well, let's take a look at the contents of the function called by `forEach`:

```
if (dataString.includes('id:')) {
  const key = metaData[index + 1].replace('key:', '').trim();
  const value = metaData[index + 2].replace('value:', '').trim();
  buffer[key] = value;
}
```

What does it do?  If one line of a file contains `id:`, take the key and value from the next line and the line after that.  If a line of a file doesn't contain `id:`, don't do anything with it.

In your case, question 2 contains more than one line, which, as we can see, your code completely ignores.

If, instead of just reading the line-after-next into the value, you want to read all lines up to but not including the next line with `id:` in it, try the following:

```
  if (dataString.includes('id:')) {
    const key = metaData[index + 1].replace('key:', '').trim();
    let value = metaData[index + 2].replace('value:', '').trim();
    
    let index2 = index + 3;
    while (index2 < metaData.length && !metaData[index2].includes('id:')) {
      value += "\n" + metaData[index2].trim();  
      index2 += 1;
    }
    
    buffer[key] = value.trim();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your entries using a regular expression and then reduce the result into key value pairs

```
const inputMatch = inputData.metaData.match(/id(.|\n|\r)+?(?=$|id)/g)

const buffer = inputMatch.reduce((acc, objectString) => {
    const key = objectString.substring(objectString.indexOf('key:') + 4, objectString.indexOf('value:')).trim()
    const value = objectString.substring(objectString.indexOf('value:') + 6, objectString.length).trim()
    return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: value
    }
}, {})
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ryv7tsb/1/)